# Regions / states / provinces icons pack png

Tags: icons, png, region, pack, countries

Does someone knows where to find Regions / states / provinces icons pack in png with there respective ISO names ?

I found https://github.com/stevenrskelton/flag-icon/tree/master/png/75

but they have 7 countries with regions ( au, br, ca, de, es, ru, us).

Is there a package with all flags from all regions of all countries ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 3 links (to download the flags of regions...)

Wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flags_of_country_subdivisions

vexilla-mundi.com : http://www.vexilla-mundi.com/new.html

Comment: Would be great to have something like a package as the question was answering.

Comment: this one is most complete I have ever seen https://forum.tsgk.com/viewtopic.php?t=4921